# How can I increase space in /home, Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: mount

My current disk uage is as:

```
$:df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdd2       1.4T   13G  1.3T   1% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev             30G  4.0K   30G   1% /dev
tmpfs           5.9G  1.9M  5.9G   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none             30G  152K   30G   1% /run/shm
none            100M   44K  100M   1% /run/user
/dev/sdd4       184G  159G   16G  92% /home
```

And my /home directly is nearly full, is any means I can use space under '/' to increase my '/home' directory?

Thanks

edit:
as requested, I post the output of sudo parted -l:

```
fhwa@FHWA:~$ sudo parted -l
Model: ATA ST3500514NS (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 500GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End    Size   Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  106MB  105MB  primary  ntfs         boot
 2      106MB   500GB  500GB  primary  ntfs


Error: Invalid argument during seek for read on /dev/sdb                  
Retry/Ignore/Cancel? Retry                                                
Error: Invalid argument during seek for read on /dev/sdb                  
Retry/Ignore/Cancel? I                                                    
Error: The backup GPT table is corrupt, but the primary appears OK, so that will be used.
OK/Cancel?                                                                
OK/Cancel? O                                                              
Backtrace has 8 calls on stack:
  8: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libparted.so.0(ped_assert+0x31) [0x7fa918be54b1]
  7: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libparted.so.0(+0x3f5f6) [0x7fa918c155f6]
  6: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libparted.so.0(ped_disk_new+0x49) [0x7fa918beaf99]
  5: parted() [0x406dff]
  4: parted() [0x407bda]
  3: parted(main+0x154b) [0x4065cb]
  2: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5) [0x7fa9183c2ec5]
  1: parted() [0x406617]


You found a bug in GNU Parted! Here's what you have to do:

Don't panic! The bug has most likely not affected any of your data.
Help us to fix this bug by doing the following:

Check whether the bug has already been fixed by checking
the last version of GNU Parted that you can find at:

    http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/parted/

Please check this version prior to bug reporting.

If this has not been fixed yet or if you don't know how to check,
please visit the GNU Parted website:

    http://www.gnu.org/software/parted

for further information.

Your report should contain the version of this release (2.3)
along with the error message below, the output of

    parted DEVICE unit co print unit s print

and the following history of commands you entered.
Also include any additional information about your setup you
consider important.

Assertion (last_usable <= disk->dev->length) at ../../../libparted/labels/gpt.c:994 in function _parse_header() failed.
```

Comment: Please post the output of `sudo parted -l` in your question.

Answer (score 0):

While you can resize the partitions, which is tedious (end an error could be disastrous), you can create folders in your home directory that are actually present on `/` (either via links or via bind mounts):

```
# First make directory in `/` to hold your data:
sudo mkdir -p /var/home-stuff
sudo chown $USER:$USER /var/home-stuff
```

Then either make a link:

```
ln -s /var/home-stuff ~/folder-in-root
```

Or bind-mount it to a folder in your home:

```
mkdir -p ~/folder-in-root
sudo mount -o bind /var/home-stuff ~/folder-in-root
sudo chown $USER:$USER ~/folder-in-root
```

<sup><sub>(You can make this bind permanent by adding an entry to `/etc/fstab`.)</sub></sup>

Now anything put in `~/folder-in-root` will actually occupy space in `/`.